# Android Fragments: Instantiating at once or instantiating when needed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have predefined set of fragments(layouts/screens) in my application. I have viewPager which contains the initial layout for user interaction(say 2 fragments). There are other fragments to display on different events and user interactions like add, edit, delete or list. Currently I am adding and removing fragments(add,edit etc) when needed.

- Does it have any performance overhead to add and remove fragments again and again?
- Should I instantiate all the fragments on application startup?
- How many fragments can we kept in memory (in case we instantiate all at once)?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that fragments have their own lifecycle, just like activities... so if you instantiate them all at once and they are not being used, when you finally get to add them to your view, they may restart their lifecycle...